# How do I force Rails to clera out cached assets (i.e. rake assets:clean is ineffective)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching, static, assets

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 on Ubuntu 14.04.  In my production environment, I would like to clear out some cached assets.  I have one in particular …

```
public/assets/modal_login-63df96ae4219892bd4aa7563655df69feaca313e1f17db6a04d7e2f56fbd48d0.css
1:#loginBox{font-family:'russo_oneregular';font-size:20px;display:inline-block}#loginLogos{position:relative}.logoRow{display:inline-block} #modalCloseButton{position:absolute;top:1px;right:5px;cursor:pointer}
```

I have made some changes to the underlying file so I would like the above to be re-generated.  I tried running the below

```
rails@ruby-rails-postgres-nginx-unicorn-1gb-nyc3-01:~/myproject$ rake assets:clean
rails@ruby-rails-postgres-nginx-unicorn-1gb-nyc3-01:~/myproject$ rake tmp:cache:clear
rails@ruby-rails-postgres-nginx-unicorn-1gb-nyc3-01:~/myproject$ ls -al public/assets/  modal_login-63df96ae4219892bd4aa7563655df69feaca313e1f17db6a04d7e2f56fbd48d0.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 rails rails 207 Oct 21 16:00 public/assets/modal_login-63df96ae4219892bd4aa7563655df69feaca313e1f17db6a04d7e2f56fbd48d0.css
```

but notice even after running the rake statements, the file in question remains.  How do I force Rails to remove all cached assets and recompile them from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the command that clears up all the mess is

```
 rake assets:clobber
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running in the rails console `Rails.cache.clear` ?